# Has anyone succeeded in interfacing Cherwell with the Twilio REST API to send SMS messages?

Tags: rest, twilio

I have been successful with sending messages to Twilio via C# and Powershell but trying to use a Web Service call in Cherwell has me stumped.

I have setup the web service call.

I'm passing all the authentication tests because I can perform a lookup for the last 50 messages (which requires authentication) but when I try to call the Messages POST with To, From and Body I get a 400 error.

Unfortunately Cherwell only shows me the 400 error and not the return text from Twilio so I can't debug any further.

If anyone has done this can you please let me know how?

Also if you could recommend a way to put an HTTPS proxy between my Cherwell server and the Twilio endpoint to view the result values, that would help me out.

Comment: Make sure you are using correct number format with or without + or 00 and country prefix for the phone number.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I am using the same format for numbers as I do with my C# and PowerShell code. I am thinking based on comments from others that this may be a JSON issue. 400 Error means that I am not including a parameter. I thought I was but it appears that maybe the Cherwell WS call is not passing JSON when I do a POST.

Comment: Can you share how you have set up the Cherwell WS call? Are you saying that Cherwell is passing JSON to Twilio? Because Twilio expects form urlencoded key/value pairs with the content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is building the message body as a single block of text that should be used as the body of the Web Service call.

Essentially, what you would have is a value that looks like

```
From=+17195550199&To=+17195550100&Body=Your text message here
```

I ran into this same issue while building this mApp to provide outgoing SMS capabilities: https://synapsesoftware.com/portfolio/twilio-mapp